# SwiperJS : Horizontal carousel with one slide expanded

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I want to create a Swiper slider in which one slide should be expanded like image below:
[image]

I'm doing it like this:

https://codepen.io/amiut/pen/poyyqye

But the problem is that when you want to open the slides that are placed on the right and left edges of the screen, a part of them will go under the screen and they are not visible.
I also tried with `translateTo` according to [swiper documentation](https://swiperjs.com/api/) to move the whole slider a little bit but that also won't work.

The CodePen I created is very simple with no animations and stuff.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what the problem is? Because if I click on the last left or right image, then it expand and show the full image. Maybe a screen record could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

- click on image will scroll to that image (centering it)
- drag the image line will change current active image

[Same example on codepen](https://codepen.io/antoncodepen/pen/poyeELM).

Some notes:

- `id='test'` and all CSS prefixes `#test` - this is just to be able to run example here on this site in code snippet
- `opacity` in CSS is just for fun
- `.swiper-slide:after` - this is just to display "real" slide index in the left top corner of every slide (I used it for testing)
- `pointer-events: none;` in CSS was used for testing, you can remove them if you need to interact with slide inner contents

```js
var featured_games = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  freeMode: true,
  freeModeSticky: false,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  loop: true,
  on: {
    click: function (swiper, e) {
      if (typeof this.clickedIndex !== 'undefined') {
        this.slideTo(this.clickedIndex);
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```css
#test .featured-game {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642702909-dec73df255d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
}

#test .featured-game .summary,
#test .featured-game .content {
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
  width: 128px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
}

#test .featured-game {
  width: 128px;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}

#test .featured-game .content {
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  transition: width 0.4s, padding: 0.2s;
}

#test .swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
    flex: 1;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#test .swiper-slide-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

#test .swiper-slide-active .featured-game {
  width: 256px;
}

#test .swiper-slide-active .featured-game .content {
  width: 128px;
}

#test .swiper-slide:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-swiper-slide-index);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container" id="test">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
  </div><!-- .swiper-wrapper -->
  
</div><!-- .swiper-container -->
```

Comment: Nice thing, the last thing i want to do is to animate the content part so it doesn't suddenly appear and does a slide effect

Comment: @Amin the difference between center slide and all others in the "visibility" of `.content` section. But visibility can't be animated. First, you need to change layout to something that is friendly to animating: 1) width + overlap:hidden, 2) opacity, 3) smth other. Of couse we can animate `width` of `.content`, but it will looks very weird :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, whatever we do the `.content` will suddenly appear which ignores any animation, do you think of a way which we can expend the slides with animating?

Comment: @Amin I've updated my answer. Now it has `width` animation (delay 0.3 seconds).

Comment: @Amin but I had to change the layout from `flex` to `position:absolute` for inner DIVs... This is just an example. Your real layout can be different

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal but you could just write to go to that particular slide on click

```
    featured_games.slideTo(swiper.snapIndex + 1)
```

Imho this can be improved

Comment: It works for one screen edge (right edge) do you think we can implement something that if the clicked slide was on the left side we could trigger `featured_games.slideTo(swiper.snapIndex - 1)` so it will go back one and if it's on the right edge it will trigger `featured_games.slideTo(swiper.snapIndex + 1)`

Comment: I managed to do this based on `event.clientX` and `swiper.width / 2`

Answer (score 1):

I set `freeMode: false` , added `slideToClickedSlide:true` and removed

```
     if (e.clientX < (this.width / 2)) {
      this.slideTo(swiper.snapIndex );
    } else {
      this.slideTo(swiper.snapIndex );
    }
    
    this.update();
```

this modification will center the slide when click on it

```js
var featured_games = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  freeMode: false,
  freeModeSticky: false,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  slideToClickedSlide:true,
  loop: true,
  on: {
    click: function (swiper, e) {
      var $slider = $(e.target).parents('.swiper-slide');
      
      
      if (! $slider.hasClass('extended')) {
        $('.swiper-slide.extended').removeClass('extended');
        $slider.addClass('extended');
          
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#test .featured-game {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642702909-dec73df255d7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80");
}

#test .featured-game .summary,
#test .featured-game .content {
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#test .featured-game .content {
    display: none;
}

#test .swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
    flex: 1;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#test .swiper-slide-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

#test .swiper-slide-active .featured-game .content {
    display: flex;
}

#test .swiper-slide:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-swiper-slide-index);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container" id="test">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="featured-game">
         <div class="summary">SUMMARY</div>
         <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
       </div><!-- .featured-game -->
     </div><!-- .swiper-slide -->
     
  </div><!-- .swiper-wrapper -->
  
</div><!-- .swiper-container -->
```